# JSON Traversing with Ternary Ops

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the following code:

```
let jsonObject = {one: {two: {three: {}}}};
let contents = [ ["text", "one", "two"], ["other text", "one", "two", "three", "four"] ... ]
contents.forEach(content => {
    jsonObject[content[1] ? content[1] : ""][content[2] ? content[2] : ""][content[3] ? content[3] : ""] = content[0];
})
```

Depending on what variables (`content[1-3]`) return a `true` boolean, it should move the JSON deeper, until it can't anymore, then finally set the value of `content[0]`. However, my code won't work since `jsonObject[""]` (along with `undefined` or `null` in place of `""`) would try to move the object deeper into a non-existent key/pair. How can I do this with one line successfully?

Comment: can you please provide json source?

Comment: @AjayOjha Edited question to have that, thanks

Comment: Your update example still doesn't make sense, what's suppose to happen in the 2nd `content` when it reaches `"four"` and no nested `"four"` property exists?

Comment: @kfedorov91 Check Nicolas Moccagatta's answer, I just need a one-liner for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this helps?

```js
contents.forEach(content => {
  if(content[1] && content[2] && content[3]) {
    jsonObject[content[1]][content[2]][content[3]] = content[0];
  } else if(content[1] && content[2]) {
    jsonObject[content[1]][content[2]] = content[0];
  } else if(content[1]) {
    jsonObject[content[1]] = content[0];
  };
});
```

Comment: Mmm I don't think that is possible in one line.

Comment: Cool! Glad to help